# Using Openvino's OpenCV build on Anaconda environment

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, openvino

I have recently installed the latest OpenVINO release (2018 R5 0.1) for Windows 10 which, if I understood correctly, comes with a fully built OpenCV. Many tutorials show the use of that OpenCV but I failed to make it work on my Anaconda environment (with Python 3.6).

---

Running the environement setup `C:\Intel\cvsdk\bin\setupvars.bat` script I get the following output:

> Commande ECHO désactivée.
>
> PYTHONPATH=C:\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.456\python\python3.6;C:\Program Files\Python36;
>
> [setupvars.bat] OpenVINO environment initialized

In my conda env, if I have no opencv package installed, I get the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named cv2`

And if I install one with `conda install py-opencv` (or `opencv`), I get this:

`cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) [...] Build OpenCV with Inference Engine to enable loading models from Model Optimizer`

Installing with pip (`pip install opencv-python`) while on the anaconda environment also doesn't work:

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) [...] Build OpenCV with Inference Engine to enable loading models from Model Optimizer`

---

For clarification, I have successfully built the opencv examples with CMake and can run the executables. Here is the output of one of their sample programs:

```
(OpenVino) C:\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.456\opencv\build\Debug>openvino_sample_opencv_version.exe
```

> Welcome to OpenCV 4.0.1-openvino

Clearly, that OpenCV is usable somehow, I just can't find how to use it in my conda environment from a python script.

Comment: Did you run: conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 opencv  OR conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv in your environment ?

Comment: @Reuben_Z I havent tried these specific ones; why would they be different than the ones I tried ?

Comment: These are the commands suggested by Anaconda itself to install OpenCV.

Comment: Either I'm unclear or you're not understanding the question; I want to use the OpenCV build that OpenVINO provides.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run

```
C:\Intel\cvsdk\bin\setupvars.bat
```

every time you activate the enviroment

Answer (score 0):

For a clean installation of openVINO & anaconda should be enough to run the environment setup, as mentioned [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-of-openvino-toolkit/topic/802287#comment-1938106), for Jupyter notebooks however could be better to run it explicitly at the beginning with:

PC

```
!C:\Intel\...\bin\setupvars.bat
```

Mac

```
!source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using windows command prompt rather than power shell, which is recommended by the official open-vino doc.

Answer (score -2):

Append OpenVINO python path in the beginning of your python code as shown below:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_<version_number>\python\python3.6")
```

For eg:

```
sys.path.append("C:\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.456\python\python3.6")
```

Comment: I will try that asap. Thanks for the help. Please know that you should Edit your answers and not post a new one ! :) I suggest you delete the other one, and if more changes are required later, edit this one.

Comment: I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'` when running on my conda environment with no OpenCV installed on it.

Comment: I created a conda environment and installed openvino. OpenCV was not installed by default so that I also got ModuleNotFoundError. But when I installed opencv using the command "conda install py-opencv" the issue got resolved and I was able to run all demos and python script in the conda environment. "pip install opencv-python" is also working for me.